# d3.js chart - speed up performance in browser

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js, graphics, charts

I have a multi-line graph with only 12 lines and zoom. Each line has around 3000 data points (and I need really more points!). View / zoom this graph in firefox browser it's barely usable. That can not be so, right?
If i remove the drawing of the data-points the performance is better.
Here is some of the important code (i use this demo: http://codepen.io/brantwills/pen/igsoc), only with 12 lines and a lot more data points:

```
dsv("/d3/data.txt", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
  // read data in Array 
});

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", zoomed);
var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear")
              .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
              .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

svg.selectAll('.line').data(data).enter().append("path").attr("class", "line")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)").attr('stroke', function(d,i){
                  return colors[i%colors.length];
                })
                .attr("d", line);
// draw points on SVG object
var points = svg.selectAll('.dots').data(data).enter().append("g").attr("class", "dots")
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

points.selectAll('.dot').data(function(d, index){
                var a = [];
                d.forEach(function(point,i){
                  a.push({'index': index, 'point': point});
                });
                return a;
                })
                .enter()
                .append('circle')
                .attr('class','dot')
                .attr("r", 2.5)
                .attr('fill', function(d,i){
                  return colors[d.index%colors.length];
                })
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + x(d.point.x) + "," + y(d.point.y) + ")"; }
                );
});
```

Comment: We really need to see some code.  Are you rendering 36000 points (`circle`) or just a line (`path`) fit to those points?

Comment: Why are you rendering 3000 points per graph? That is probably way above the resolution of most screens. You should sub-sample your data and re-render when you zoom in.